# ftp_connect fatal error : call undefined function

Tags: php, ftp, osx-mountain-lion

For some reason the ftp_connect() function doesn't work, when I try to used it it ends with a fatal error stating that this function is undefined... Surprisingly I can still use a ftp client or use an ftp connection through the Terminal. How may I solve this problem ?

I run on Mountain Lion et I've got the 5.3 php version - I reinstalled it once hoping this would solve my problem.

Answer (score 19):

Check [PHP FTP installation manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ftp.installation.php)

On PHP 7, You can enable it by adding this line to the php.ini file.

```
extension=php_ftp.dll
```

On PHP 8+ enable this line in php.ini:

```
extension=ftp
```

Answer (score 13):

I ran into the same issue. After I checked this one setting, it worked just fine.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like your PHP was not installed with `--enable-ftp` or that the ftp module is disabled in your php.ini.

To check if ftp is enabled, create a page like this and browse to it:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Look for "ftp support", it should be marked "enabled".

Comment: I don't even find "ftp support", does that mean that it's not installed ?

Comment: Yes, actually it would never say "disabled".

Comment: I've gone through a new installation of php (5.4) and I now have the line `FTP support enabled`, still I've got that error : `Fatal error: Call to undefined function ftp_connect() in ...`

Comment: I don't know what could be wrong, my PHP 5.3 works with FTP on Mountain Lion with no particular setup. It may be a stupid question, but have you restarted Apache after reinstalling PHP? (sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart)

Comment: Yes I restarted apache. The error doesn't seem to come from the php itself, maybe it's because of the deamons agent, how may I check that ?

Comment: Ok, then I really have no idea what could be wrong. There is no daemon for PHP. There is one for Apache (but it is working), and then Apache loads the PHP library (this is also working) that must have FTP enabled (which seems to be the case). I don't see what else could disable FTP support.

Comment: You might want to verify if you have 2 PHP versions running. You might be running script with one PHP which does not have ftp extension enabled and your apache might be running another PHP version with ftp extension enabled.

If that is the case, run the script with later PHP version and check if it helps.

My 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

I found that (at least for higher versions of PHP), that Luboš Turek's answer is mostly correct. On Windows, at least, you don't need (or want) the ".dll" suffix.

What is very odd is that the PHP.INI default configuration file doesn't even include a commented out line stating:

```
;extension=php_ftp
```

So, as Luboš said, adding:

```
extension=php_ftp
```

to the INI will work. That said, check your **ext** folder to make sure the FTP extension is there.

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for an answer and fixed mine by changing the setting in php.ini as below. I removed the leading semicolon on the ftp extension line (at the bottom).

```
; - Many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) or ext/ (PHP 5+)
; extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5+).
; Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.
;
extension=bz2
extension=curl
;extension=dba
extension=com_dotnet
;extension=enchant
extension=fileinfo
extension=ftp
```

Answer (score -1):

Guys I find the Solution, For me I had PHP 5 and now I have PHP 7. I get this error. Do this:
Open **PHP.INI**
Search for : **allow_url_include = Off**
Change *Off* to *ON*:
Like this: **allow_url_include = On**

**Restart all Service** on Wamp server

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, i fix it disabling the antivirus or add the apache server to the exception.